# SFAuthenticationSession completion handler not called

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, safari, sfauthenticationsession

I am trying to implement an approach to exchange cookies from Safari and App. I am using `SFAuthenticationSession` since the cookies sharing was disabled. I read through the topic and it seems this is the best solution to achieve this. There are not too many blogs or repos to use as an example.

I have implemented the changes redirect in the server side as following.

First I store the cookie as `https://example.com/?cookie=12345`. Then from the app I start an Authentication Session pointing to `https://example.com/getcookie` which redirects to `customapp://dummy/cookies?cookie=12345`

Once stated this. The swift implementation is the following (thanks to [this](https://github.com/dvdhpkns/SFAuthenticationSession-Instagram-Oauth)):

```
let callbackUrl  = "customapp://dummy/cookies"
let authURL = "https://example.com/getcookie"

self.authSession = SFAuthenticationSession(url: URL(string: authURL)!, callbackURLScheme: callbackUrl, completionHandler: { (callBack:URL?, error:Error? ) in
    guard error == nil, let successURL = callBack else {
        return
    }

    let cookie = self.parseQuery(url: (successURL.absoluteString), param: "cookie")
    print(cookie!)

    })

self.authSession?.start()
```

You may notice I am not interested on signing in but getting a cookie stored previously.

Can anyone please advice? My problem is that although the site is redirecting, the completion handler is not called, so I can't parse the callback url.

**UPDATE**

I found out I was missing the protocol in the `Info.plist`. After adding the custom protocol to it, the handler was called. Nevertheless, the handler was only called the **second** time I engaged the Authentication Session.

Any clue?

Comment: Hi, Can you share the complete set up to set the SFAuthenticationSession, What protocol need to add in Info.plist